# Is there a way to configure X-Frame-Options in SharePointOnline?

Tags: sharepoint-online, iframe

I'd like to be able to embed certain file previews from SharePoint Online in another domain - in fact, I'd like to do it for 2 extra domains.

Is it possible to replace this header...

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

with this one?

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/ https://example2.com/
```

Or is this just a limitation of SharePoint Online?

OneDrive and OneDrive for Business don't add the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header, so I can embed from OneDrive. SharePoint Online is more restrictive.

Comment: Nope. This is defined in server-side code (even in SharePoint 2016).

Comment: So this means that its impossible to embed SharePoint Online files in a web page on a separate domain, right? That sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Microsoft has this locked down.